# iOS 6 Simulator

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded the xcode for iOS6 along with the simulator. Now, when I run my cocos2d project, the screen doesnt follow along with the device turns. It always stays in the "up" position, when it used to always stay in the "right" position. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 6 introduces a new mechanism for nominating supported interface orientations; see 'Handling View Rotations' in [the UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The short version is that unless you implement [`-supportedInterfaceOrientations`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) on your view controller to further limit the options then whatever orientations you specified as supported in your Info.plist will be used.

So quite probably you want to click on your project in the top left hand corner of the Xcode project navigator, select your target in the left-hand bar of the content on the right, then 'Summary' in there and ensure you have only the landscape right orientation selected.

E.g.

[image]